# API to find a resource in Eclipse workspace tree

Tags: eclipse-plugin, find, workspace

Is there any API available to find a resoruce(java file) in Eclipse workspace tree when a resource name is given? I mean recursively.

Thanks.

Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search at any level of the workspace, even the top starting with `org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()`.  Then use something like:

```
root.getRoot().accept(myResourceVisitor);
```

See the [javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/package-summary.html) for `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.accept(IResourceVisitor)` for more information.

PW

Comment: I ended up writing my own version of recursive method since an answer wasn't ready for a while. I will definitely try your suggestion. Thank you.